# An ID number for a product when added keeps changing when the form is reloaded

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, northwind

I have recently began to go back over database programming in vb and I am using the Northwind database to test with.

On my program I have add, edit and delete functionality for the Products. When I add new product to the table using Windows Forms, the Product ID is incremented fine (If the last product ID is 70 the new product will be 71) and then I update the database.

However a problem I keep having is when say I debug my form again and go to the last product that I just entered, the ID has changed from 71 to 84 and I am unsure as to why it has done this. Here is the code that I have for the add function, if you need to see any other parts of my code then let me know and thanks for the help :)

```
 Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    newProduct = NorthwindDataSet1.Products.NewProductsRow()
    newProduct("ProductName") = txtProdName.Text
    newProduct("UnitPrice") = txtUnitPrice.Text
    newProduct("Discontinued") = cbxDiscontinued.CheckState
    newProduct("ProductID") = NewProdID
    Try
        NorthwindDataSet1.Products.Rows.Add(newProduct)
        Try
            Me.Validate()
            Me.ProductsTableAdapter.Update(Me.NorthwindDataSet1.Products)
            MsgBox("Update successful")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Update failed")
        End Try
    Catch x As Exception
        MsgBox("This does not work")
    End Try

    btnAdd.Visible = False
    btnDelete.Enabled = True
    btnCancel.Enabled = True
    btnFirst.Enabled = True
    btnLast.Enabled = True
    btnPrevious.Enabled = True
    btnNext.Enabled = True
    btnNew.Enabled = True
    lblProdID.Visible = True

    ProductsBindingSource.ResumeBinding()
    lblLastPos.Text = ProductsBindingSource.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the ProductID an IDENTIY or Autonumber column in your database? If yes you don't have control on its value but you get what the database engine gives back to you

Comment: The ProductID is an autonumber as a primary key. The last product has the ID of 77 but new products added will be given a number in the 80's as I believe it is counting for the test products which I added and deleted

Comment: Expanding on what has been indicated, autonumbers are not meant for human consumption. Yes, when a new record is initially begun, the new autonumber value is 'used'. Even if you never save the record or save and then delete it. If it is important to not have gaps in the numbering, then you need to use just a long integer field and increment it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless if your insert query goes completed or not, every insert attempt to an Access database table will increase the auto number field.

it is common, auto numbered fields will produce gaps from like deleted records or failed inserts. You can only maintain continuous numbering if your table never perform delete action or if you have a custom id field and reset the counter upon deletion of records. This will also require manually increment your custom id.

Best way just ignore the gaps.. :)